# How to use "pmap" on linux to find the memory usage of a program I wrote

Tags: linux, memory, pmap

I understand I can use: pmap pid 
where pid is the process id I'd like to run pmap on, but what if I have a program that I wrote that simply executes once then closes, how would I get the pid for this process?  Would it even have a pid after it closes?

As an example lets say I have example.c, which I've compiled into example.

I run it using ./example
and it runs once then closes.

How would I use pmap to see the memory usage of example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [`pause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html) at the end of your `main` and do:

```
pmap `pidof example`
```

Alternatively, without changing example, you could run it under `gdb` and break whenever you want to examine the memory with `pmap`.